# Merging streams of different types into one

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore, stream

I think this is going to be a stupid question but I need to ask anyway.

Can I use StreamZip() to merge 2 streams of different types?

I have integrated the table_calendar into my flutter app but I did this by creating a specific collection and data structure for events. Here is the Event data model:

```
  final String? eventName;
  final DateTime? eventStartTime;
  final String? eventDuration;
  final DateTime? eventDate;
  final String? eventDescription;
  final String? agentId;
  final String? agencyId;
```

However, I realized that I have dates in another collection that I would like to add to the table_calendar and display them as markers in the grid and in the list below the calendar grid.

This is the second collection data model:

```
  final String? trxnId;
  final String? clientFName;
  final String? clientLName;
  final String? contractDate; // THIS IS A DATE
  final String? sellerDisclosure24a; // THIS IS A DATE
  final String? dueDiligence24b; // THIS IS A DATE
  final String? financing24c; // THIS IS A DATE
  final String? settlement24d; // THIS IS A DATE
  final String? inspectionDate; // THIS IS A DATE
  final String? appraisalDate; // THIS IS A DATE
  final String? closingDate; // THIS IS A DATE
  final String? walkThroughDate; // THIS IS A DATE
```

I need to know if I can create 2 streams and combine them. I am thinking that for displaying markers in the table_calendar grid all I really need is the date of the event. For the list of events below the calendar grid I need the date, title would be the data field name (i.e. sellerDisclosure24a), startTime can be null for the second model, description can be client first and last name, duration can be null for the second model. So if I combine them each of the 8 data fields in the second model would need to be it's own entry in the stream.

Is this possible to do?

I hope this makes sense. Please let me know if it is clear as mud.

Answer (score 2):

You can combine different type streams with `StreamZip`. All you need to do is to pass your streams in a list to `StreamZip` and use `map` method to combine your data. You can even create a simple method using it to combine streams easily:

```dart
Stream<C> combineStreams<A, B, C>(
  Stream<A> a,
  Stream<B> b,
  C Function(A, B) combiner,
) {
  return StreamZip([a, b]).map<C>((values) => combiner(values[0] as A, values[1] as B));
}
```

Here is how you will use it:

```dart
// Combine Event Stream and Other Stream
final Stream<Result> stream = combineStreams<Event, Other, Result>(
  // Event Stream
  myEventStream,
  // Other Stream
  myOtherStream,
  // Function that combines the event of streams
  (event, other) {
    // Create a new model from event model and other model
    return Result(event, other);
  },
);

// Subscribe to stream event
stream.listen((result) => print(result));
```